# Basic regex for 16 digit numbers

Tags: c#, .net, regex, windows

I currently have a regex that pulls up a 16 digit number from a file e.g.:

Regex:

```
Regex.Match(l, @"\d{16}")
```

This would work well for a number as follows:

> 1234567891234567

Although how could I also include numbers in the regex such as:

> 1234 5678 9123 4567

and

> 1234-5678-9123-4567

Comment: Are all groups always composed by 4 digits?

Comment: Always in groups of four, no others?

Comment: @Yorye Nathan No there are not any others

Answer (score 3):

If all groups are always 4 digit long:

```
\b\d{4}[ -]?\d{4}[ -]?\d{4}[ -]?\d{4}\b
```

to be sure the delimiter is the same between groups:

```
\b\d{4}(| |-)\d{4}\1\d{4}\1\d{4}\b
```

Comment: Would \b\d{4}([- ]?)\d{4}\1\d{4}\1\d{4}\b be more readable? The pipe after the empty string hurts my brain!

Comment: @LexyStardust: It's just a matter of taste

Comment: M42 agreed, Regexes are a window on the soul. Or something!

Answer (score 1):

If it's always all together or groups of fours, then one way to do this with a single regex is something like:

`Regex.Match(l, @"\d{16}|\d{4}[- ]\d{4}[- ]\d{4}[- ]\d{4}")`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
^([0-9]{4}[\s-]?){3}([0-9]{4})$
```

That should do the trick.

Please note:
This also allows

1234-5678 9123 4567

It's not strict on only dashes or only spaces.

Comment: Doesn't match when there're no delmiters, ie 1234567890123456

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to just use the regex you currently have, and strip all offending characters out of the string before you run the regex:

```
var input = fileValue.Replace("-",string.Empty).Replace(" ",string.Empty);
Regex.Match(input, @"\d{16}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern which will get all the numbers and strip out the dashes or spaces. Note it also checks to validate that there is only 16 numbers. The ignore option is so the pattern is commented, it doesn't affect the match processing.

```
string value = "1234-5678-9123-4567";
string pattern = @"
^                   # Beginning of line
(                   # Place into capture groups for 1 match
  (?<Number>\d{4})    # Place into named group capture
  (?:[\s-]?)          # Allow for a space or dash optional
){4}                  # Get 4 groups
(?!\d)                # 17th number, do not match! abort
$                   # End constraint to keep int in 16 digits
";

var result = Regex.Match(value, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
                  .Groups["Number"].Captures
                  .OfType<Capture>()
                  .Aggregate (string.Empty, (seed, current) => seed + current);


Console.WriteLine ( result ); // 1234567891234567

// Shows False due to 17 numbers!
Console.WriteLine ( Regex.IsMatch("1234-5678-9123-45678", pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace));
```

Comment: True...but the OP needs to give us an example which demonstrated the need to work within a file...we shouldn't have to read their mind to figure out the multitude of permuations which could be the case.